# Send form disabled fields values to server

Tags: php, html

I am trying to send value to server through post method.Some fields are disabled.Server can't get this value.If i put readonly attribute then its fine.But the main problem is when the textfield is date field.It is showing disabled but user can input date through calendar.

Please tell me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: disabled fields don't get submitted. end of story. If you want them to be submitted, then they can't be disabled, or you have to use JS to copy their values into hidden fields which ARE submitted.

Comment: Here's a brilliant idea - do not put readonly nor disabled and then you can both change it and send it to the server. Incredible, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its true that readonly attribute takes input from calendar.I think it will be nice if you put disabled attribute but when you will click on submit button that time you can change attribute to readonly using javascript .